# beginUpdates endUpdates crash with nothing between

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I am entirely confused.  I am modifying my table and it's crashing while up via adding/deleting rows and reloading sections.  So I stopped adding and deleting rows, and it still crashes.  So I stopped reloading sections and it still crashes.  So I just put the code:

```
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

with this code it crashes, without it's fine.

Why?

2014-09-12 21:52:41.257 weatherApp[12616:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ea84f83 0x392ffccf 0x2e9bb7cb 0x3149eaef 0x3149cd8f 0x3149c843 0x31474e5b 0xeb82d 0xed059 0x313d48f7 0x3137bc27 0x3137b47d 0x312a1d59 0x30f1f62b 0x30f1ae3b 0x30f1accd 0x30f1a6df 0x30f1a4ef 0x30f6dc49 0x33d3a75d 0x2f770451 0x2ea44ea9 0x2ea4fa67 0x2ea4fa03 0x2ea4e1d7 0x2e9b8ebf 0x2e9b8ca3 0x33912663 0x3130514d 0x107599 0x3980cab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Edit:  Be advised I am calling this update in cellForRowAtIndexPath because I need to check for an update as new cells are displayed.  The code that causes this update is the [self updateSection code, which right now only runs begin updates, end updates.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

WFHNotamTableViewCell *cell = (WFHNotamTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell)
{
    NSLog(@"Dequeue blank cell");
}
NSLog(@"Loading %d - %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
NSString *group;
NSString *icao = [metarManager getIdentifierAtTotalIndex:indexPath.section andReturnGroup:&group];
NSMutableDictionary *notamDict = [notamManager getNotamFor:icao atVisibleIndex:indexPath.row];

NSDate *lastUpdate = [notamDict objectForKey:@"timeDownloaded"];

[self updateSection:indexPath.section andLastUpdate:lastUpdate];

return cell;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Edited it with the code

Comment: I don't quite understand your "Be advised" note, but generally you should not modify the overall table from inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  If I need to check for updates often (especially before loading a new cell), then when should I check for it?  Is there a different delegate method that's better?  Thank you!

Comment: beginUpdates/endUpdates has nothing to do with checking for updates.  They control animation.  (What kind of "update" are you checking for?)

Comment: Yah, so I was surprised those caused a crash with nothing between.  I'm downloading data in the background and therefore changing the datasource while the table is displayed.  I have a way to check if there is new data, which I'd like to then reload the section if it is.  It doesn't happen often, but when it does it can cause a crash if it removes or adds rows

Comment: Well I learned, do not update a section while running cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Causes all kinds of issues. Find a different time to check for updates.  Thanks!